# determining the number of a noun clause

Tags: grammar

Is it "All I want for Christmas *is* my two front teeth" or "All I want for Christmas *are* my two front teeth"?

Comment: From the sense. Is *all* referring to a collection that's an entity that acts or has a state of its own? Or is it a collection of individuals in which each individual acts separately?

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_I_Want_for_Christmas_Is_My_Two_Front_Teeth) for the song *All I Want for Christmas **Is** My Two Front Teeth*, which I assume is what the OP is referring to,

> He asked his second grade class what they wanted for Christmas, and noticed that almost all of the students had at least one front tooth missing as they answered in a lisp.

Going by above *two front teeth* seems to be a collection i.e. a single thing.